# libGDX Toast message

Tags: libgdx, toast

I have tried to use this tutorial:

http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=484#p2959

Firstly have declared `private Toast render_toast = new Toast(7, 6);`

After that putted `render_toast.toaster();` to render.

I would like to use it in show, so I have put this to `show()`:

`render_toast.makeText("Game start", "font", Toast.COLOR_PREF.BLUE, Toast.STYLE.ROUND, Toast.TEXT_POS.middle_right, Toast.TEXT_POS.middle_down, Toast.MED);`

It isn't working, gives no error message, only stop my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an interface for required methods in your game. Implement this method in your AndroidLauncher class, using libgdx handler. You can call these methods anywhere in your game for Android related UI.

You can follow this video for details,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxiT3pkIiDQ

This is how, I used it in my game.

```
 //Defining interface for customized methods
public interface AndroidInterfaces {

    public void toast(final String t);

}

//implementing the interface in android launcer
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements AndroidInterfaces{

    final AndroidLauncher context=this;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();    
        //if (Gdx.input.isPeripheralAvailable(Peripheral.Compass))
          cfg.useCompass = true;
          //cfg.useAccelerometer=true;
        initialize(new MyGame(this), cfg);
    }

    @Override
    public void toast(final String t) {
        handler.post(new Runnable()
        {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //System.out.println("toatsing in launcher run");
                Toast.makeText(context, t, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });

    }
}


public class MyGame extends Game{
    //16012016
    //16012016 for toast
        AndroidInterfaces aoi;

        public MyGame(AndroidInterfaces maoi)
        {
            aoi=maoi;
        }
        public MyGame()
        {

        }
      public boolean backpressed=false; //Universal flag to check back button press status , across screens.
       .....
      .....
}



public class MainMenuScreen implements Screen{

    MyGame game;
    float x,y,w,h,pw,gap;
    float x1,y1;   //coordinates for animation
    //16012016
    boolean toast=false;
    float toasttimer=0;

    public MainMenuScreen(MyGame gg) {
        game = gg;
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {           
        //16012016
                if(toast)
                {
                    toasttimer=toasttimer+delta;
                }
                .....
                ...//omitted
            //16012016:Toast
            if(toast)
            {
                if(toasttimer> 2.5)
                    Gdx.app.exit();
                else if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.BACK))  //For double back press exit effect.
                    Gdx.app.exit();
            }
            else if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
            game.setScreen(game.STS);  //Setting another screen
        }       
        //16012016
            else if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Keys.BACK))
             if(!game.backpressed)
                {
                 if(!toast)
                 {
                     toast=true;  //if bsck button is just pressed in current screen then toasting..
                  game.aoi.toast("EXITING.THANKS FOR PLAYING!");  //Not relevant to desktop project, calling implemented method in androind launcher
                 }       
                }
                                                    }
         else if(game.backpressed)
         {
             game.backpressed=false;
         }
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        //16012016
                toasttimer=0;
                toast=false;
                Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(true);  
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Some english tutorial would be much more greater.

Comment: Video link is dead. I found this one helpful: https://youtu.be/8H75oJD0I0g

Answer (score 4):

I have implemented Android-like toast for my project and decided to share it with you! Enjoy: [Toast LibGDX (GitHub)](https://github.com/wentsa/Toast-LibGDX)